# $f$ monotonically decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ with limit zero implies $f$ positive

Tags: calculus, limits

I got this question:

Let $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $ \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$
such that $f$ is monotonically decreasing on $[0,\infty)$, must it be the case that for all $x \in [0,\infty), f(x)>0$ ?

From an intuitive point of view it sounds true but I tried to prove it but failed so far.

Comment: True with $f(x)\geq 0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $f(x)\ge f(y) $ when $x \le y$. Hence $f(x) \ge \lim_{y \to \infty} f(y) = 0$ for all $x$.

If the relationship is strict, then so is the conclusion, for the same reason.

**Elaboration**: 
Let $\epsilon>0$, then there is some $M$ such that if $y \ge M$, then $-\epsilon < f(y) < \epsilon$. If we take $y \ge \max(M,x)$ we get (by monotonicity) $f(x) \ge f(y) > -\epsilon$. Hence $f(x) > -\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. From this we conclude $f(x) \ge 0$.

If the relationship is strict, then $f(x) > f(x+1)$. By the above reasoning, we have $f(x+1) \ge 0$, hence $f(x) > 0$.

Comment: this captures the intuition perfectly. much proof. such satisfying. many beautiful. so $\lim$. wow.

Comment: The inequality should be strict! Anyway the proof is nice.

Comment: Nice solution, but how do I prove that for all $x \in [0,\infty), f(x) \geq \lim_{y \to \infty} f(y)$ by using the definition of limit?

Comment: I will add an elaboration.

Comment: Surely your proof (although very nice) does not work for strict inequalities, as taking the limit only preserves regular inequality, not strict inequality.

Comment: @JoshuaPepper: Wow, tough crowd. I have added a little more elaboration.

Comment: Nice proof! thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there's $x_0\ge 0$ such that $f(x_0)\le0$ so for $x_1>x_0$ we have 
$$f(x_1)<0$$

Let $\epsilon=-f(x_1)>0$, from the definition of the limit there's $A>0$ such that for all $x>A$ we have
$$f(x)\ge-\epsilon= f(x_1)$$
and the last inequality gives an obvious contradiction. We conclude that
$$f(x)>0\quad \forall x\ge0$$